# Insert a GPS module to my ThinkPad , possible?

Tags: thinkpad, gps

Is it possible to insert a micro GPS module into my laptop , which is a ThinkPad X220 ?

Something that like BIOS clock , that can power itself without external source.

(Just some thought , but if you know any manufacturer in Europe / North America , please let me know)

Thanks.

Comment: I do believe one of the options - the 'gobi' wwan chipset includes gps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy a MiniPCI GPS card to replace your existing WiFi card. Apparently the mobile broadband card option for [some ThinkPads](http://www.tjansson.dk/?p=450) is an Ericsson F3507g mobile broadband card with integrated GPS. It isn't clear to me whether the GPS is a true standalone device or if it uses cellphone tower triangulation, since you must [insert a SIM card and enter a PIN to activate the GPS](http://3g-modem.wetpaint.com/page/Ericsson+F3507G).

You can also buy an USB GPS receiver, but I think they usually use the USB cable as the antenna, so I'd look into the MiniPCI options first.